# Stacking divs and variables

Tags: html, css, image, web, slideshow

I have a navigation bar and an image slider under it. how can i stack them on top of each other? my goal is for the images in the slider to be the background-image of the navigation bar. Help me please. The navigation bar consists of a simple div, but the image slider (made in js) is a variable, and not a div. So basically i want to the div to be on top of the slider, i already set the div opacity to low so the images of the slider are visible. Thank you rich i will send the code now.

Comment: How about posting you code or making fiddle. Wouldn't that help us helping you better...??

Comment: Dear Richa, how can i send you the code? should i put it in the question?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0765nfeb/

Comment: I will senf all the js, html and css, but ignore the images in the slider they are test images with the wrong size. Just tell me where should i send it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i will do a fiddle immediately

Comment: Im having trouble making a fiddle being a first timer... can i send you the code by e-mail?

Comment: hello? anyone there? :(

Comment: To make this a topic others can use as well, you need to post something here or in a fiddle (not in a mail)

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble since my code is really long

Comment: this is why I'm looking for someone that can help me so i can send him the code privately, because i feel that my code is too specific for it to be answered without the proper code

Comment: do you think you could help me if i send you the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
margin-top:0px;
```

put this in your css file for the nav-bar and the slider and it should move everything to the top.

Comment: This would just put no gap between the top of your content of your second element and the bottom of your first element.

Comment: thank you so much i will be trying it in a minute and letting you know about the result

Comment: than you for the suggestion but sadly I'm not being able to select my slider. it is made in 4 parts, 4 variables, i will try doing this for all 4

Comment: don't you have an overall div for the slider?

Comment: its really complicated because the slider i took from js made easy so no there is no div wrapping it

Comment: if i send you the code by email you will understand it better, can you give me your email address

Comment: just make a div called slider. in that div you put the images that are displayed in the slider.

Comment: where do i put that div?

Comment: Dear vinc. you were incredibly kind and i thank you very much. your solution worked.